# CSS - Float Left + Padding = Last Div Go Down?

Tags: css, css-float, padding

3 Column with float left, each with 33.33% width. And I added padding to make the column looks more neat. But apparently the last DIV is pushed to new line. Any solution for this one? Here also I come out with reproduction for reference.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.row {
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  margin:40px auto;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  overflow:auto;
}
.col {
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px
}

.ful-dark {
  opacity:0.9
}

.mid-dark {
  opacity:0.8
}

.lil-dark {
  opacity:0.7
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col ful-dark"><h1>One</h1></div>
  <div class="col mid-dark"><h1>Two</h1></div>
  <div class="col lil-dark"><h1>Three</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`, which forces the provided size to be the full size, including any order and spacing such as your padding.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  margin:40px auto;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  overflow:auto;
}
.col {
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px
}

.ful-dark {
  opacity:0.9
}

.mid-dark {
  opacity:0.8
}

.lil-dark {
  opacity:0.7
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col ful-dark"><h1>One</h1></div>
  <div class="col mid-dark"><h1>Two</h1></div>
  <div class="col lil-dark"><h1>Three</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding unfortunately doesn't count by default in sizing, so the width + padding makes each actually wider than a third. `box-sizing: border-box` is a wonderful tool to combat this, making all padding & borders part of the width measurement:

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  margin:40px auto;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  overflow:auto;
}
.col {
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px
}

.ful-dark {
  opacity:0.9
}

.mid-dark {
  opacity:0.8
}

.lil-dark {
  opacity:0.7
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col ful-dark"><h1>One</h1></div>
  <div class="col mid-dark"><h1>Two</h1></div>
  <div class="col lil-dark"><h1>Three</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because of the padding. try putting `box-sizing: border-box;`, this will keep the container's `width` when a padding is declared.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.row {
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  margin:40px auto;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  overflow:auto;
}
.col {
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ful-dark {
  opacity:0.9
}

.mid-dark {
  opacity:0.8
}

.lil-dark {
  opacity:0.7
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col ful-dark"><h1>One</h1></div>
  <div class="col mid-dark"><h1>Two</h1></div>
  <div class="col lil-dark"><h1>Three</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want 3 * (padding-right + padding-left + width) to equal 100%.

Try

```
.col {
  float:left;
  width:31.33%;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  padding:1%;
}
```

Comment: You're not wrong, but you're doing it the hard way. `box-sizing: border-box` does this automatically.